# Search for files using Droid Explorer

Tags: windows, search, droid-explorer

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 rooted. Is it possible to search for files using Droid Explorer and Windows 7? If it is possible, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, no. You cannot search from within droid explorer for files. This is something that I eventually want to do, but have not yet had the time to do so. (I am the developer of droid explorer).